# Check if object's atribute was defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

In this code example, how can i  say : " if color was not defined "?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def atribute(self, color):
        self.color = color


object1 = A('car')
object2 = A('ship')

object1.atribute('blue')

if not object2.color:
    object2.atribute('red')

print(object2.color)
```

Output error i get when run this code : "'A' object has no attribute 'color'"

Comment: FWIW, `color` is an attribute, not a method (and even less a "classmethod" - which is something with a well defined meaning in Python).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, there is a diferent terminology to refer to the atribute 'name' and the atribute 'color', or are both just atributes ?

Comment: @VitorOliveira `self.name` and `self.color` are both just attributes here.

Comment: @ruohola Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use `if hasattr(object1, 'color')`, but this looks like a bad design from the get go (put a side that defining an attribute outside of `__init__` is both confusing and violates PEP8).

I will suggest to use a property with a default value of `None`, then you can use a straightforward `if` check (and it is clear by looking at `__init__` what properties `A` instances have):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, color=None):
        self.name = name
        self._color = color

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        # some logic you may need before setting color to value
        self._color = value

object1 = A('car')

if not object1.color:  # or if object1.color is None:
    object1.color = 'blue'
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers As the comment in my code suggests, just in case OP needs some logic when setting `color` (otherwise, the `method` method (...) in OP's code does not make sense)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hasattr` function:

```
if not hasattr(object2, 'color')
    object2.method('red')

print(object2.color)
```

But this smells like a really bad design pattern and you should probably rethink your implementation.